# Angular2 recursive component - set input autofocus

Tags: angular, recursion, input, autofocus

I'm creating a tree view similar to workflowy (for practice mostly), and this simple version is working but I can't figure out how to set the input focus when a new component is added.

I've tried adding the autofocus property on the input and using ViewChild to set focus after ngAfterViewInit. It seems to work when adding the first component but not thereafter.

Here is a stackblitz to show where i'm at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-autofocus

Answer (score 0):

the easer way to "autofocus" in a recently component created is using ViewChildren

```
  @ViewChildren() items!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.items.changes.subscribe((r) => { 
         //If you want to focus to first
         this.items.first().nativeElement.focus();
         //or if you want to focus to last
         this.items.last().nativeElement.focus();

  }
```

But, seeing your stackblitz, I can not imagine what you want to do

Comment: Sorry I know its a mess. When I update the items array in my item.service angular will update the entire dom to add or update the new item and i want to focus the input on the item that has just been updated. I have the right functionality now by using a boolean to find which item has just been edited - see the setAutofocus method in my items component. But this seems messy and its run on every change detection cycle so its called a lot.. I'm sure there's a better way of doing all of this..