# How to add AutoFocus directive to inputs on click?

Tags: angular, typescript

On clicking button "Add", I want to add an input with the directive AutoFocus.
The auto focus is working only on first add.
In my HTML, on add button click, there is only one input with the directive autofocus.

this is my directive code:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appAutoFocus]'
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements OnInit {

    private _autofocus;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this._autofocus || typeof this._autofocus === 'undefined') {
            // this.el.nativeElement.focus();
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.el.nativeElement.focus();
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    @Input() set autofocus(condition: boolean) {
        this._autofocus = condition !== false;
    }

}
```

My HTML contains many cases but I add it:

```
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="item_key" *ngIf="addFirstParam && containersParams.length == 0">
        <span class="key_span">Key</span>
        <input [(ngModel)]="model.urlParams" appAutoFocus
               #urlParams="ngModel"
               name="urlParams"
               class="add_key"
               (input)="addParamsToUrl($event.target.value)">
        <span (click)="deleteLastFromParamList()" class="delete_item"><i
                class="icon-bin"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="urlParamsList.length > 0">
        <div class="item_key" *ngFor="let container of urlParamsList; let i = index;">
            <span class="key_span">Key</span>
            <input value="{{container}}" class="add_key" (input)="updateParamsInUrl($event.target.value, i)">
            <span (click)="deleteFromParamList(container, i)" class="delete_item"><i
                    class="icon-bin"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="containersParams.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let container of containersParams">
            <div class="item_key elem_{{container}}">
                <span class="key_span">Key</span>
                <input [(ngModel)]="model.urlParams"
                       #urlParams="ngModel"
                       name="urlParams"
                       class="add_key" appAutoFocus
                       (input)="addParamsToUrl($event.target.value)" >
                <span (click)="deleteLastFromParamList()" class="delete_item"><i
                        class="icon-bin"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div (click)="addKeyRequestParams()" class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="canAdd">
        <span class="for-btn icon-plus"></span>
        <span i18n="@@newEndpointBtn">Key</span>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-cancel" *ngIf="!canAdd">
        <span class="for-btn icon-plus"></span>
        <span i18n="@@newEndpointBtn">Key</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I activate the autofocus on every click?

Comment: Can you add the HTML code here?

Comment: Another aproach is use ViewChildren and susbcribe to changes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507958/angular2-recursive-component-set-input-autofocus